# Match and replace block using regex with sed on Solaris

Tags: sed, solaris, solaris-10

This is working on some tools as regex101.com but I cannot make it work with sed.

Blocks:

```
dn: abcd1,ou=test
aaaaa
bbbb
1111

dn: abcd2,ou=test
33333
ddddd
aaaaa

dn: qwert,ou=test
55555
hhhh
dddd
```

I want to match and replace with nothing every block that starts with `dn: abcd`. A block always ends with `\n\n`.

Regexp: `(?s)\b(?:(?!\n\n).)*?\bdn: abcd\b(?:(?!\n\n).)*`

Is it possible to achieve with sed?

Comment: try using `perl`... sed doesn't support lookarounds or non-capturing groups and many other features that are available in perl...

Comment: also, if you could modify given input sample without `\n` (assuming you have literal newlines and not ``\`` followed by `n`) - use the `{}` button in editor to format the sample instead of backticks.. and add complete expected output, it'd help to suggest solutions..

Comment: @Sundeep already edited, thanks! I'm not familiar with perl, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[perl](/questions/tagged/perl) is a better choice for this task.

```
$ perl -00ne 'print if not /^dn: abcd/' file
```

or

```
$ perl -ne 'print if not /^dn: abc/ .. /^$/' file
```

```
dn: qwert,ou=test
55555
hhhh
dddd
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `awk`'s paragraph mode

```sh
$ awk -v RS= '!/^dn: abcd/' ip.txt
dn: qwert,ou=test
55555
hhhh
dddd
```

- `-v RS=` When RS is set to empty string, one or more consecutive empty lines is used as input record separator
- `!/^dn: abcd/` to ignore paragraphs starting with `dn: abcd`

note that default output record separator is single newline, so you might need something like this:

```sh
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '!/^dn: abcd1/' ip.txt
dn: abcd2,ou=test
33333
ddddd
aaaaa

dn: qwert,ou=test
55555
hhhh
dddd
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this sed

```
sed '/^dn: abcd/,/^$/d' infile
```